# Why can't I debug a script task in SSIS if there's an interpolated string?

Tags: ssis

In trying to create a script task in SSIS, I couldn't figure out why it was refusing to let me debug when I had a breakpoint on the first line of the script. Through process of elimination, I finally realized it was because I had an interpolated string in the form:

```
var myString = $"Here's a thing: {thing}";
```

If I replace that with:

```
var myString = "Here's a thing: " + thing;
```

Then suddenly it allows me to debug again. Is there some setting I'm missing, or is this a bug in SSIS?

They both work the same. It's just a matter of not being able to debug.

Comment: I usually use string.Format("Here is a thing: {0}", thing); which is closest to your first method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in SSIS extension component for Visual Studio. To fix it you have to install Visual Studio 2019 and [SSIS component](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) for it; the bug was fixed in version 3.2, current version is 3.4.
Unfortunately, this fix is not backported to SSIS extension components for VS 2017 and older, so you have to upgrade to VS 2019.